# Navigate to Another Form from System Tray Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, system-tray

I am working on a WinForms application, I tried to minimize the form to system try while closing and when opening from the system tray I want to directly go to the main app without logging again.
The main point is to reduce the login attempts to get into the main app and the app should run in the background until the account holder logs out of the app and sees the login screen.

This is what I am up to

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Splashscreen());
        Application.Run(new SignIn());                                       
    }
```

This is how I navigate to the main app from sign-in form

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        waitForm.Close();
        this.Hide();
        //Nothing to do with this system tray problem, just checking for another valid condition
        if(condition == true)
        {                 
            MainApp mainapp = new MainApp();
            mainapp.ShowDialog();                
        }            
        this.Close();
    }
```

Main App to get into after login

```
private void MainApp_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            this.Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;                
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

But, When I do this, the system tray icon disappears and cannot go to the specified page. Any thoughts or experience in making this happen?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you need the instance of `SignIn` or is not needed anymore after `MainApp` is shown?

Comment: @Steeeve  I don't need the sign in instance and when the user logs in the mainapp should be shown and after minimizing to tray the mainapp should be shown with logged-in user's account

Comment: I would then separate the `SignIn` form completely from `MainApp` and change the `static Main()` so that it shows SignIn with ShowDialog and if login successfull `Application.Run(new MainApp())`

Comment: @Steeeve I need to start from signin and go on to mainapp. How can have two main methods..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that hiding a form ends the `ShowDialog()` modal loop. So in `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` your `SignIn` form gets closed when the `MainApp` form is hidden and exits the `Application.Run()` loop in the main method. See my comments in your existing code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    waitForm.Close();
    this.Hide();
    //Nothing to do with this system tray problem, just checking for another valid condition
    if(condition == true)
    {
        MainApp mainapp = new MainApp();
        // this method will exit when mainapp will be hidden:
        mainapp.ShowDialog();
    }
    // this will exit your Application.Run(new SignIn()) in the static Main methods:
    this.Close();
}
```

As you said you don't need the `SignIn` instance after a successful login, you could change your app as follows.
In `SignIn` form change the following method like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    waitForm.Close();
    //Nothing to do with this system tray problem, just checking for another valid condition
    DialogResult = condition ? DialogResult.OK : DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

This way you can use the `DialogResult` of `SignIn` in your `Main` method in `Program.cs`:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Splashscreen());
    using (var signIn = new SignIn())
    {
        switch (signIn.ShowDialog())
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
    Application.Run(new MainApp());
}
```

The rest of the code looks Ok at the first glance.

Comment: Thanks Mate, But when I simply close the signin form without any credentials, the mainapp appears after that. Here's my workflow => [workflow](https://gist.github.com/nlora/648acbff23f77c586df632dfae413b20).

Comment: That's because you changed my code in program.cs. It must be as I wrote it, otherwise it continues without authentication.

Comment: Also there is no need for a notifyIcon or mainApp in SignIn.cs. I'm not sure what `button1_Click` should do, if you need to run the mainApp, always close the SignIn with `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` instead of Close() or Hide(). And remove `SignIn_FormClosing`

Comment: But, I want to authenticate with credentials for normal users and USB for admins

Comment: Replace `this.Close()` with DialogResult = DialogResult.OK in ´button1_Click` and remove `this.Hide();` (latter would also end the ShowDialog loop).

Comment: Dude... @Steeeve, This method works on debug but not on release. Can you tweak something so that `break;` does not break the app from running? Cause that was the problem it seems ... after login the app just closes and does not open.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that I dug out from a very long time ago (more than a decade ago).  Windows 10 broke it a bit, so there are a few recent changes.  One of the things you are going to want to do (if you are canceling closing) is to handle `WmQueryEndSession` and `WmEndSession` messages - otherwise your app will keep the system from shutting down.

```
private const int WmQueryEndSession=0x11;
private const int WmEndSession=0x16;
```

Here's some extracts from some working code.  It's just copy/paste from an archive.  I don't have a VS system I can test this code on right now.

Here's the end session code:

```
//needed to get this thing to close cleanly.  OnSessionEnding and OnSessionEnded didn't work
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
    switch(m.Msg){
        case WmQueryEndSession:
            m.Result=(IntPtr) 1;        //basically "e.Cancel = false;"
            goto case WmEndSession;
        case WmEndSession:
            forceExit=true;
            Close();
            return;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

*Note that that comment about `OnSessionEnding` and `OnSessionEnded` may date from the days of Framework v1.x; it may not be true today*

The `forceExit` flag is initially false.  It gets set when the user clicks the close button with the control key held down or choses `Quit` from a context menu.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    if(forceExit)
        return; //close and quit
    //otherwise
    forceExit=false;
    if(!ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Control)) {
        WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized;
        e.Cancel=true;
    }
 }
```

I have a `Restore` option in my context menu (that's how the the form is restored).  This app has it's greatest use in the *Notification Area* (aka *System Tray*).  When in its restored form, it's mostly used to change app settings, etc.  From the comments, I needed to fiddle things here after Win10 came out:

```
private void RestoreCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Show();
    //restoring from initially minimized on Windows 10 seems to completely mess up all the control positions and sizes
    //so store everything here and restore it below
    Dictionary<Control, (Point location, Size size)> controlPositions = null;
    if (textBox1.Size.Width != 0)
    {
        controlPositions = new Dictionary<Control, (Point pos, Size size)>();
        foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls.Cast<Control>())
        {
            controlPositions.Add(ctrl, (location: ctrl.Location, size:ctrl.Size));
        }
    }

    WindowState=FormWindowState.Normal;
    //restore all the control positions and sizes
    if (controlPositions != null)
    {
        foreach (var position in controlPositions)
        {
            position.Key.Size = position.Value.size;
            position.Key.Location = position.Value.location;
        }
    }
}
```

There are `Hide` and `Quit` entries in the context menu:

```
private void HideCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void QuitCmd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    forceExit=true;
    Close();
}
```

There's a ton of functionality in this app.  I think I've extracted all the show/hide management and put it in this answer.  If I'm missing something, let me know.

Comment: yeah mate, I understood what is happening, But the system tray icon is still disappearing and I'm sure you are close to it but it is not working the way I wanted... Or can u explain to me where this all code goes?

Comment: @opuscorpus: The `WndProc` code is a standard Windows Forms way to get into the Form's (/window's) Win32 WndProc. Just drop it in your form class. The `FormClosing` event handler handles that event for the form. My tray icon has a context menu with several entries. Three of them are `Restore`, `Hide` and `Quit`. Those are the corresponding event handlers